# Activating animation when within radius

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I am trying to create a script for my enemy turret, but it is not going well. I have a couple animations of the turret being activated and deactivated. What I need is that based on the distance from the player, it plays either animation. So once it moves inside the detection radius it plays the activation animation and once it is outside it plays the deactivation animation. Most of the other ways I try require me to create an Animation Controller, which I have little experience in using. I want a simple way to play one animation once it is inside and play a different one when it is outside. I think there was a way to store the animation clip in the script, and then play it. I have attached my current script, so you know what I mean.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyTurret : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject Player;
public float DistanceToPlayer;
public float DetectionRadius = 75;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PlayerTank");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    DistanceToPlayer = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.transform.position);
    if (DistanceToPlayer<=DetectionRadius)
    {
        Debug.Log("Within Radius");
    }
    if (DistanceToPlayer >= DetectionRadius)
    {
        Debug.Log("Outside Radius");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Calculating and checking the distance of the player for every update() is not ideal. It will work, but it will do more work than it needs to when the player isn't even near it. Its not efficient.

What you may want to do if your player is a Rigidbody, is add a SphereCollider to the turret, set isTrigger=true, set the radius to be your detection radius, and handle the OnTriggerEnter() and OnTriggerExit() events to play or stop animations.

You can also add two public Animiation objects to the script, drag and drop your animations in the editor, then you can use animation.Play() and .Stop() etc. to control the animations.

Something similar to this. Not tested fully, but you can get the idea.

```
public float detectionRadius = 75;
public Animation activateAnimation;
public Animation deactivateAnimation;

void Start()
{
    SphereCollider detectionSphere = gameObject.AddComponent<SphereCollider>();
    detectionSphere.isTrigger = true;
    detectionSphere.radius = detectionRadius;
    detectionSphere.center = Vector3.zero;
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "PlayerTank")
    {
        activateAnimation.Play();
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "PlayerTank")
    {
        deactivateAnimation.Play();
    }
}
```

Your animations must not loop otherwise you will have to add more logic to check if animation.isPlaying and do your own animation.Stop() etc.

Comment: Hi, I have replaced my script with your script, but there is a couple of problems.  I have created two gameObjects as a child of the Turret GameObject. Each has its own Animation Component. As it's animation I have stored the animation clip. It still won't though play the animation. I not sure I made this clear in my question, but I don't have an Animator, only Animation Clips. The .Play(), doesn't seem to play the animation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you copied my script exactly, in the editor you should see 2 animation slots, one named "Activate Animation" and the other "Deactivate Animation". All you have to do is drag the Animation component from each of the child gameObjects onto each of the slots to link them, and activateAnimation.Play() will play the animation linked to the Activate Animation slot. Then deactivateAnimation.Play() will play the other animation in the other slot.